# IntelliJ Jetbrains language Annotation @Language("SQL") not works but @Language("sql") works

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

As title, language annotation `"SQL"` not works while `"sql"` works. I have search many articles but it seems everyone use language id `"SQL"` works instead of me.

Anyone knows what's going on here ? Or there is any workaround to make language id `"SQL"` works.

- IntelliJ Version: Community 2020.2
- JDK Version: openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
- Jetbrains Annotations version: 19.0.0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA Community edition does not have SQL language support. See comparison matrix [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html). To use it try Ultimate edition to work with [sql and databases](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/relational-databases.html) and [inject sql into another languages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-injected-sql-statements.html).